# GROUP BY clause not working in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using following dependency for connecting with azure cosmos db

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```

And using this query

```
"SELECT c.parentid, COUNT(1) AS count FROM collection c WHERE c.parentid != 'null' GROUP BY c.parentid"
```

And I am getting following error -

```
{"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":91,"end":96},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'GROUP'."}
```

Is there any configuration I am missing in Java application or is group by not supported?

Comment: If you go into the data explorer (in the Azure Portal) you can run SQL: do you get the same error there?

Comment: But also `'null`" is a string, did you mean `where c.parientId is not null`?

Comment: yes I mean where c.parientId is not null (null string)

Comment: First thing to check: naming collision. You named a column `count` which is also a reserved word. Does the error change if you rename `count` to something else? Or still an error? Note: even if it has nothing to do with the error, I suggest not using keywords as column names.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - error is still the same after renaming

Comment: @Richard - I am not sure how to access data explorer in azure portal. I am using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. Could there be issue with java dependency I am using?

Comment: To access in portal: go to the Cosmos DB instance, on open the data explorer blade. Select a container's items and one of the icons across the top is "New SQL Query"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an old version of the Java SDK that does not have support for GROUP BY.

Please upgrade to the latest Java SDK v4. The dependency section should look like this.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
   <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are new to using the v4 Java SDK it has both sync and async modules included. You can take a look by following this here, [Quickstart: Build a Java app to manage Azure Cosmos DB SQL API data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-java?tabs=sync)

Comment: I am getting this error with above dependency - Failed to instantiate [com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient]: Factory method 'cosmosClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA